# como podría arreglar mi código de python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

NECESITO AYUDA CON ESTO.
Este es mi enunciado:.
tengo que hacer una app que calcule porcentajes de una empresa que vende coches, aviones, barcos y trenes según sus beneficios, además tengo que identificar si faltan datos y este es mi código, sin embargo me da fallos y no se como arreglarlos, si pudieseis ayudarme os lo agradecería.

---

````
def sumaListas(a,b,c,d):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        s.append(a[i]+b[i])
 
    return s
 
coches= []
aviones = []
barco = []
tren = []

s = []
 


menu = int(input("hola puedes calcular el porcentaje tus beneficios con esta app, ¿cuales son tus beneficios? "))
coche = int(input("cuantos coches has vendido? "))
coches.append (coche)
avion = int(input("cuantos aviones has vendido? "))
barcos =int(input("cuantos barcos has vendido_?"))
trenes = int(input("cuantos trenes has vendido?"))
divisor = (sumaListas(coches, aviones, barco, tren))
adios = ("gracias`por haber usado este programa")
pregunta_porcentaje = input("quieres ver tus porcentajes?")
if pregunta_porcentaje == "si" :
    print ("Tu porcentaje de coches vendidos es del", coches / divisor * 100)
    print ("Tu porcentaje de aviones vendidos es del", aviones / divisor * 100)
    print ("Tu porcentaje de barcos vendidos es del", barco / divisor * 100)
    print ("Tu porcentaje de trenes vendidos es del", tren / divisor * 100)
    
    print (adios.title())
elif pregunta_porcentaje == "no":
    print (adios.title())
elif coches == None :
    print ("te faltan por poner los coches")
elif aviones == None :
    print ("te falta por poner los aviones")
elif barco == None :
    print ("te falta por poner los barcos")   
elif tren == None :
    print ("te falta por poner los trenes") ```
_________________________________________________________________________________
````

Comment: No podemos ayudarte si no nos dices cuáles son los fallos que tiene. Mira cómo crear un [example].

Comment: gracias, intentare identificar los fallos y lo editaré para que este de la mejor forma posible.

Comment: Mencionaste que tu código tiene fallos: ¿qué fallos? Pulsa en [edit] y especifica cuáles son. Además, pon en el título cuál es el problema _específico_ que tienes: "cómo podría arreglar mi código de python" no da pistas del problema. Recuerda que tu pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar.

Answer (score 1):

Manteniendo tu lógica, dentro del primer for cambiamos lo siguiente:

```
s = a[i] + b[i] + c[i] + d[i]
```

Completamos los input:

```
avion = int( input( "cuantos aviones has vendido? " ))
aviones.append( avion )
barcos = int( input( "cuantos barcos has vendido? " ))
barco.append( barcos )
trenes = int( input( "cuantos trenes has vendido? " ))
tren.append( trenes )
```

En la impresión de los resultados:

```
print ("Tu porcentaje de coches vendidos es del", coches[0] / divisor * 100)
print ("Tu porcentaje de aviones vendidos es del", aviones[0] / divisor * 100)
print ("Tu porcentaje de barcos vendidos es del", barco[0] / divisor * 100)
print ("Tu porcentaje de trenes vendidos es del", tren[0] / divisor * 100)
```

Ahora bien, no creo que esto sea lo que te están pidiendo, creo que deberías pedir la cantidad vendida, luego pedir el valor de cada unidad y guardarlo en el array correspondiente.
Luego en **sumaListas**, recorres cada lista con el for, para ir sumando sus valores y cargarlos en la variable correspondiente, y sumas las cuatro varibles.
El resto del código sería más o menos el mismo.
Agrego el código completo que me funciona...

```
def sumaListas(a,b,c,d):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        s = a[i] + b[i] + c[i] + d[i]
    return s
 
coches= []
aviones = []
barco = []
tren = []
s = []
 
menu = int(input("hola puedes calcular el porcentaje tus beneficios con esta app, ¿cuales son tus beneficios? "))
coche = int(input("cuantos coches has vendido? "))
coches.append (coche)
avion = int( input( "cuantos aviones has vendido? " ))
aviones.append( avion )
barcos = int( input( "cuantos barcos has vendido? " ))
barco.append( barcos )
trenes = int( input( "cuantos trenes has vendido? " ))
tren.append( trenes )
divisor = sumaListas(coches, aviones, barco, tren)
adios = "gracias`por haber usado este programa"
pregunta_porcentaje = input("quieres ver tus porcentajes?")
if pregunta_porcentaje == "si" :
    print ("Tu porcentaje de coches vendidos es del", coches[0] / divisor * 100)
    print ("Tu porcentaje de aviones vendidos es del", aviones[0] / divisor * 100)
    print ("Tu porcentaje de barcos vendidos es del", barco[0] / divisor * 100)
    print ("Tu porcentaje de trenes vendidos es del", tren[0] / divisor * 100)
    
print (adios)
```

Comment: gracias, lo probaré y espero que funcione

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!

Comment: Recién copié el código completo, lo probé varias veces y no arroja errores, fijate si tenés alguna diferencia, yo saque el ***adios.title()** porque no se de donde sale el **.title()** y me daba error, quité las comprobaciones finales, que no tenían sentido, y después no hay mucho más, para que te dé **IndexError: list index out of range on line 3**, tendrías que estar creando array de distinta longitud, o vacíos, pero con el código como está, no veo como podrías.